# Remove red circle from image in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am aware that Chrome puts blue borders around buttons and images.
However, I have encountered one more thing that Chrome does.

I have an image that I would like to act like a button. The image of the star gets a red circle when clicked. (Not in other browsers.)

The code for the image is this:
`<input type="image" src="star.png">`

Here is the css:

```
input[type=image]{
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px; 
  cursor: pointer; 
  outline: none;
  border-style: none;
}
```

The weird thing is that the circle does not surround the image (which is a square), but the "content" of the image.

How can I get rid of this?

Thank you.

[screen grab: red circle around an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOCmb.png)

Comment: I'm not aware of Chrome doing that. I don't see it in my example: https://codepen.io/kjantzer/pen/VyXBjJ

Comment: Can you create a fiddle that recreates the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When selected use the focus selector like so

```
 input[type=image]:focus {
 outline: none;
 border-style: none;
 }
```

Working [pen](https://codepen.io/sajrashid/pen/vpRaWO)

Comment: @Tyler, to mark your post as completed/solved/ answered click the tick under the answer & a green tick appears underneath.